# javascript - how to draw boxes in columns

Tags: javascript

I'm projecting a calendar and, although a little bit familiar with PHP for the backend, I'm struggling with the front end which will be in Javascript.
I'm trying to keep things simple as I'm still in the learning process, so basically, the table is created using bootstrap/CSS and it shows the present weekdays from Monday to Sunday. 
I'd like now to add some front end in order to draw the boxes when I click/drag the mouse over the cells. When done the script will save the start date/ end hour in a MySQL database.
The problem is, how can I draw those boxes?

Ways I was thinking how to do that:

1. **Keep things simple**: basically, I will not draw any boxes but simply color the background and the line of those cells selected on the even .onmousedown

   2. **Try the hard way:** try something harder and better looking and explore better the world of libraries in JS. I was looking in JCanvas thing, but for my level, I still have to understand better how it works.

The problem then is how to pass the parameter of these boxes to a backend script that saves the start/end hour. Of course, I was thinking to give to every cell a specifical id with hour/date, so I think it'd be easy to recall them both for drawing the calendar event with the mouse and also to draw all the present events on the database when the table is loaded.

What can approach do you suggest me to take? Any input would be great!

Thank in advance
Luca!

PS: I'm not expecting full code or whatever, just doing some projects in order to learn more!

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I suggest you look at some javascript calendar plugins that to help you select dates by dragging. And if you really must do it yourself, pick apart those plugins and learn how to...

Answer (score 0):

I think the first option will work great. Adding the background color and  border on the selected cell will help in highlighting.

You'll also need some of the things listed below:

1. [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX): To communicate with the back end script.
2. [Events - Bubbling and Capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing): You don't really have to put the event on every cell but the whole table, you could capture the event target with `event.target`.

Comment: yes I 'll follow the first way and then make it more complex on my way! Thank you for your feedback and resources